# Using Wordpress/WooCommerce with Existing Restful Service

Tags: wordpress, web-services, rest, e-commerce

Our small company has a already existing Restful Service, where we have all of our products on our own bespoke fulfilment system.

We have looked at Wordpress to start developing our sites in and we have developed a page to consume our Webservice and display a product with a particular promotion, and also bring back prices.

However, could you integrate WooCommerce (or perhaps another eCommerce package) which can consume our webservice? Thus, we would not populate WooCommerce with our products, they will pull it from our Webservice. Also enabling users to login/renew via a Webservice call also?

If anyone could give any tips/advice I'd be grateful. I know this is possible through general Webservice development - however I wanted to know if this is achievable through an prebuilt eCommerce package.

Many Thanks